# Ionic using reactive forms will cause show issue?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic-native, ionic6

Will i face any issues while using reactive forms in Ionic?

1. I am using [(ngModel)] fearing that reactive forms causes issues like
   `<ion-input [(ngModel)]="value"></ion-input>`
2. I am very much comfortable with reactive forms will i face any issues

```
<form [formGroup]="signup">
  <ion-input formControlName="firstName"></ion-input>
</form>
```

3.Did any one used reactive forms in production? if you wrote did you found any different behaviour from angular? if you didn't find any please post that worked fine

Comment: ngModel not working in reactive form

Comment: Ngmodel is working I want to use reactive forms will I face any issues further?